# Using UIKitView from Chameleon in ARC not working

Tags: macos, osx-chameleon

I am trying to use the chameleon framework ( https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon ) to use iOS UI elements in OSX.

For me to do this, I've to use:

```
[kitView launchApplicationWithDelegate:delegate afterDelay:1];
```

But probably since the framework is made for non-arc, I am getting the error:

```
**ARC Semantic Issue:** Receiver type "UIKitView" for instant message is a 
forward declaration.
```

Anyone any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use `@class UIKitView`?

Comment: @TimvanElsloo added it but still not working. I did read my question again and it may be not clear, so I'm building in a ARC enabled app. Which is causing the problem. With ARC disabled I don't get this error.

Comment: Thanks for helping, problem was I imported UIkit.h and not UIKitView.h , pretty dumb mistake.